# Problema con elifs i variables locales

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Me gustaría saber porque el compilador me escribe lo siguiente:
local variable 'randomindexmother1' referenced before assignmen.
He estado buscando i según por lo que he visto, no necesito tratar randomindexmother1. El problema lo tengo en los elif, en el inicio, randomindexmother1 i randomindexfather1 son mayores que 2 por tanto se tendría que cumplir el tercer elif i el quarto pero solo se me ejecuta el tercero.

```
 def generation(listPaths):
    # This function will give us the new generation of kids
    # we will introduce the survived paths
    # This function will take as input the list sorted paths and sorted fitnesses of each path
    # listP will be a list produced in a while statmentself.
    rand1 = 0
    rand2 = 0
    lunusedindex = []
    newpaths = []
    i = 0
    fpoint = listPaths[0][0][0]
    lpoint = listPaths[0][0][-1]
    mother = []
    father = []
    kid1 = []
    srtlist = []
    # this is going to be the random number between the fitness of the maximum path fitness and the minimum of
    # the half population
    leng = len(listPaths)
    lunusedindex = range(leng)
    while i < leng / 2:
        # here we select an aleatory father and an aleatory mother
        rand1 = random.choice(lunusedindex)
        rand2 = random.choice(lunusedindex)
        if rand1 == rand2:
            while rand1 == rand2:
                rand1 = random.choice(lunusedindex)
        # here we delete the mother and the father selected to not repeat a father and mother
        del lunusedindex[rand1]
        if rand1 < rand2:
            del lunusedindex[rand2 - 1]
        else:
            del lunusedindex[rand2]
        k = 0
        while k < 2:
            mother = copy.deepcopy(listPaths[rand1][0])
            father = copy.deepcopy(listPaths[rand2][0])
            del mother[0]
            del mother[-1]
            del father[0]
            del father[-1]
            indexfather = range(len(father))
            indexmother = range(len(mother))
            kid1.append(fpoint)
            j = 0
            ref = 0
            rem = 0
            while j < len(father) or len(mother):
                # with this statment we ensuring that less points are going to be repeated and if mother or father
                # become empty, this means that all the points are used but some of them can be repeated
                if len(indexfather) <= 2:
                    randomindexfather1 = random.randint(indexfather[0], indexfather[1 - ref])
                    del indexfather[0:randomindexfather1 + 1]
                    ref += 1
                    if len(indexfather) == 0:
                        randomindexfather2 = randomindexfather1 + 1
                    else:
                        randomindexfather2 = random.randint(indexfather[0], indexfather[1 - ref])

                elif len(indexmother) <= 2:
                    randomindexmother1 = random.randint(indexmother[0], indexmother[1 - rem])
                    del indexmother[0:randomindexmother1 + 1]
                    rem += 1
                    if len(indexmother) == 0:
                        randomindexmother2 = randomindexmother1 + 1
                    else:
                        randomindexmother2 = random.randint(indexmother[0], indexmother[1 - rem])

                elif len(indexfather) > 2:
                    randomindexfather1 = random.randint(indexfather[0], (len(indexfather) - 2))
                    del indexfather[0:randomindexfather1 + 1]
                    randomindexfather2 = random.randint(indexfather[0], (len(indexfather) - 1))

                elif len(indexmother) > 2:
                    randomindexmother1 = random.randint(indexmother[0], (len(indexmother) - 2))
                    del indexmother[0:randomindexmother1 + 1]
                    randomindexmother2 = random.randint(indexmother[0], (len(indexmother) - 1))

                kid1.extend(father[randomindexfather1:randomindexfather2])
                kid1.extend(mother[randomindexmother1:randomindexmother2])
                del father[randomindexfather1:randomindexfather2]
                del mother[randomindexmother1:randomindexmother2]
                j += 1
                # with this code we take parts of the parents until they will be empty,the problem is that points are going to be repeated
            kid1.append(lpoint)
            for x in kid1:
                inde = random.uniform(0, len(kid1) - 1)
                if kid1[inde] in kid1:
                    del kid1[inde]
            distances = []
            totdist = 0
            z = 1
            while z < len(kid1) - 1:
                # menys 1 ja que tenim len(kid1)-1 intervals
                distances.append(distpoint(kid1[z - 1], kid1[z]))
                totdist = sum(distances)
            newpaths.append([kid1, totdist])
            k += 1
        i += 1
    srtlist = sorted(newpaths, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    return srtlist

x = [[[[3, 4], [2, 4], [5, 8], [2, 4], [4, 5]], 5], [[[3, 4], [6, 8], [4, 6], [6, 4], [4, 5]], 4]]

Y = generation(x)
print Y
```

Comment: Los `elif` son siempre mutuamente excluyentes, es decir, si da cierta la condición y ejecuta ese caso, ya no ejecutará el resto de "casos" `elif`. Si lo que quieres es que pueda ejecutar varios, usa `if` en lugar de `elif`. No obstante, no me he parado a mirar si realmente es ese tu caso, pues no entiendo el cometido del código. Y tampoco veo claro que eso esté relacionado con la excepción que te da.

Comment: Para complementar, `randomindexmother1` es una variable que está declarada dentro de dos de los bloques de `if.. elif`, y la usas fuera, pero si por la lógica la ejecución no pasa por esa parte de código, la variable no habrá sido declara, por consiguiente el error.